# Calculate calendar date for recurring item

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calendar

Provide the ability to calculate/ create a recurring task that is the 1st Thursday of the month minus 1 day.  There does not appear to be an out of the box configuration to do this.

User needs the ability to calculate/ create a recurring task that is the 1st Thursday of the month minus 1 day.

Comment: Isn't that the same as making a recurrence Monthly, Pattern the first Wednesday of every 1 month?

Comment: Actually, no, I guess it isn't, because Wed might be in the next week, if that's a concern.  But in my lazy way, I'd do that, then go and move the ones that were incorrect manually.